# Micronaut with IBM DB2 database

Tags: micronaut, micronaut-data

I am trying to create Micronaut Rest API along with IBM DB2 as a backend layer.  As per Micronaut dialect configuration, I could see only H2, MQSQL, PostGres, SQL_server, Oracle available and no DB2 available.

Is there any standard way to connect DB2 via JPA process ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use Hibernate, the dialects you see are for Micronaut JDBC/R2DBS which don’t support DB2.